# SQL Server FOR XML nesting fragment

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to produce an XML fragment such as the following

```
<Owner>
 <Individual>
  <Name>
   <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
   <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  </Name>
  <Address>
   <CountryCode>NL</CountryCode>
   <AddressFree>123/456/Netherlands/Netherlands</AddressFree>
  </Address>
 </Individual>
 </Owner>
 <Owner>
 <Individual>
  <Name>
   <FirstName>Tony</FirstName>
   <LastName>Hancock</LastName>
  </Name>
  <Address>
   <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
   <AddressFree>123/Maryland/United States</AddressFree>
  </Address>
 </Individual>
</Owner>
```

I am writing this SQL:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT  
         b.GivenName [Name/FirstName] ,
         b.FamilyName [Name/LastName] ,
         b.Address_Country [Address/CountryCode] ,
         b.AddressFree [Address/AddressFree]
     FROM    
         dbo.stage_Clients_Merge b
     WHERE   
         b.DWHClientNo = @dwhclientNo
     FOR XML PATH('Individual'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('Owner'), TYPE;
```

But this code doesn't return the required output, instead it wraps both individuals in the same owner.

How can I change this to achieve what I need to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Urgh posting when sick is not the way to go! I need two separate Owners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you have added the parents `Name` and `Address`, you can add an additional parent, 'Individual'

```
SELECT  
     b.GivenName [Individual/Name/FirstName] ,
     b.FamilyName [Individual/Name/LastName] ,
     b.Address_Country [Individual/Address/CountryCode] ,
     b.AddressFree [Individual/Address/AddressFree]
FROM dbo.stage_Clients_Merge b
WHERE b.DWHClientNo = @dwhclientNo
FOR XML PATH('Owner'), TYPE
```

Comment: Great that works. An additional question though if I may. If I extend the problem further and have another table from which I want to select data, orders for example. If I use a sub select to get all the orders for the client and the same technique then I get the <Individual> twice.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask another question properly - it will get more attention. Also, if this was correct, please could you mark as answer.